# Why my Photoshop brush pixelated instead of smooth

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

Sorry, I don't know how to describe this strange behavior.
I have no idea what happened on my brush...
Please help me.
Thanks a lot!!
[image: strange brush]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE @Echo Yang. Unfortunately it seems like this question is pretty broad and seems like it's off-topic as it may fall under the technical support category as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can be different reasons for why this might be happening but you may have changed either your brush Mode to "Dissolve" or your Layer Blending Mode is set to "Dissolve".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thks a lot! That's the problem. :>

Comment: Next question: why is it so easy to stumble finger your way into this inscrutable mess? :(

Answer (score 1):

You may have accidentally selected a different brush. This can be changed under the brush presets panel. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The brushes you are using also may be or a low resolution. E.G. They were created in a small size, and making the size bigger than they were created to do will change the clarity. Just like low res files do when they are added onto a high res file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that I had accidentally changed mode from "normal" to "dissolve". When your brush tool is active, check that the mode box on the top menu shows "normal". This solved it for me.

Comment: it has already been mentioned in another answer, maybe you should focus on unanswered questions instead. Besides, if you think one particular question or answer is useful you can upvote. Check the [tour] to learn more about how this site works.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure you select Brush and not a pencil with "brush" settings.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

For me I just went to *reset all tools* and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Image > Mode > choose higher B/Channel